# Replacing last word in a line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I replace different last words in a line in Notepad++?

e.g.

This is line one 
This is line two 
This is line three 
etc.

Replace with:

This is line /one/ 
This is line /two/ 
This is line /three/ 
etc.

Thanks. 
Marco

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to surround the last word in a line with slashes, you can accomplish this task very easily by using regular expressions: In your Notepad++ window press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, choose the tab titled 'Replace' and select 'Regular Expression' search mode.

Use `(\w+)$` as your search pattern in the 'Find what' field. Because of the parentheses Notepad++ will create a backreference meaning that the matched string inside the parentheses will be stored for further use.

1. `\w` matches any word character (alphanumeric + underscore)
2. `+` is a greedy quantifier and matches the previous item once or more, as many times as possible.
3. `$` Matches at the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to, in this case before line breaks.

In your case you'd use the following pattern in your 'Replace with' field: `/\1/`. `\1` references the stored match from your first parentheses.

A good place to start with regular expressions is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). You can try your regular expressions at [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: Thank you. It seems for a newby I was on the right track, well almost (-: Also thanks for the Expressions links.